# Alternatives for for loops in R?

Tags: r, code-coverage, bioinformatics

I got 2 files which I'd like to combine using R.

```
head(bed)
chr8 41513235 41513282 ANK1.Exon1
chr8 41518973 41519092 ANK1.Exon2
```

The first one is giving intervals and their names.
(Chromosome, from, to, name)

```
head(coverage)
chr1 41513235 20
chr1 41513236 19
chr1 41513237 19
```

The second one is giving coverages for single Bases.
(Chromosome, position, coverage)

I now want to get the name of each Exon written next to each Position. This will result in some positions with no "Exon" which I want to delete afterwards.

I figured out a ways how to do what I want. However it needs 3 for loops and about 15 hours computing time. Since for loops are not best practice in R I'd like to know if anyone knows a better way than:

```
coverage <- cbind(coverage, "Exon")
coverage[,4] <- NA

for(i in 1:nrow(bed)){
 for(n in bed[i,2]:bed[i,3]{
  for(m in 1:nrow(coverage)){
   if(coverage[m,2]==n){
    file[m,4] <- bed[i,4]
   }
  }
 }
}

na.omit(coverage)
```

Since all of the three positions lie in the intervall "ANK1.Exon1", the output should look like this:

```
head(coverage) 
chr1 41513235 20 ANK1.Exon1 
chr1 41513236 19 ANK1.Exon1 
chr1 41513237 19 ANK1.Exon1
```

Comment: An example output would be useful, but could this be done with a simple merge?

Comment: I suggest to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: The output should look like this:
head(coverage)
chr1 41513235 20 ANK1.Exon1
chr1 41513236 19 ANK1.Exon1
chr1 41513237 19 ANK1.Exon1
I did not know that it is possible to merge intervals in R. I'm trying to find out more about that now. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Stern, can you edit your original question with this information rather than post it in a comment; it makes it much easier to find and understand for others later. Look in to the `join` commands in `dplyr` package if your data is huge.

Comment: hi, is `coverage` and `bed` sorted ? .... the algorithm may to be lineal O(max(N,M)) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to perform what I was looking for was:

```
library("sqldf")
res <- sqldf("select * from coverage f1 inner join bed f2
on(f1.position >=f2.'from' and f1.position <=f2.'to')")
```

The calculation time went down to seconds. 
To get the exact result as indicated above the dataframe was further reduced.

```
res <- cbind(res[1:4],res[8])
```

Thank you all for your help.

Edit: For large datasets were the same positions may appear in more than one Chromosome it is helpfull to further add:

```
res <- sqldf("select * from coverage f1 inner join bed f2
on(f1.position >=f2.'from' and f1.position <=f2.'to' and f1.Chromosome = f2.Chromosome)")
```

Comment: Since `from` is an SQL keyword it should be put in quotes: `f2.'from'`.  Ditto for `to` .

Answer (score 2):

this algorithm is lineal, if `bed` and `coverage` inputs are sorted, and `bed` input isn't intevals overlapping

```
> coverage <- read.table("coverage")
> bed <- read.table("bed")
> 
> coverage <- cbind(coverage, "Exon")
> coverage[,4] <- NA
> 
> i_coverage <- 1
> i_bed <- 1
> 
> while(i_coverage <= length(coverage[,1]) && i_bed <= length(bed[,1])) {
+   if(coverage[i_coverage, 2] < bed[i_bed, 2]){
+     i_coverage <- i_coverage + 1
+   }else{
+     #then coverage[i_coverage, 2] >= bed[i_bed, 2]
+     if(coverage[i_coverage, 2] <= bed[i_bed, 3]){
+       coverage[i_coverage,4] <- as.character(bed[i_bed, 4])
+       i_coverage <- i_coverage + 1
+     }else{
+       i_bed <- i_bed + 1
+     }
+   }
+ }
```

you get:

```
> print(coverage)
V1       V2 V3     "Exon"
1 chr1 41513235 20 ANK1.Exon1
2 chr1 41513236 19 ANK1.Exon1
3 chr1 41513237 19 ANK1.Exon1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GenomicRanges:

```
library("GenomicRanges")

#data
x1 <- read.table(text="chr1 41513235 41513282 ANK1.Exon1
chr1 41518973 41519092 ANK1.Exon2")

x2 <- read.table(text="chr1 41513235 20
chr1 41513236 19
chr1 41513237 19")

#Convert to Granges object:
g1 <-  GRanges(seqnames=x1$V1,
               IRanges(start=x1$V2,
                       end=x1$V3),
               Exon=x1$V4)


g2 <-  GRanges(seqnames=x2$V1,
               IRanges(start=x2$V2,
                       end=x2$V2),
               covN=x2$V3)
#merge
mergeByOverlaps(g1,g2)

#output
# DataFrame with 3 rows and 4 columns
#                            g1       Exon                          g2      covN
#                     <GRanges>   <factor>                   <GRanges> <integer>
# 1 chr1:*:[41513235, 41513282] ANK1.Exon1 chr1:*:[41513235, 41513235]        20
# 2 chr1:*:[41513235, 41513282] ANK1.Exon1 chr1:*:[41513236, 41513236]        19
# 3 chr1:*:[41513235, 41513282] ANK1.Exon1 chr1:*:[41513237, 41513237]        19
```